# How does the camera app prevent its toolbars from rotating while the image and its buttons do?

Tags: ios, ios7, rotation, autorotate

I noticed that when rotating the IOS camera APP its toolbars do not rotate.

The toolbars do not rotate but the content and buttons on the toolbar do rotate?

How can I achieve this effect?
It would be great if I could have some viewControllers on the same view 
return shouldAutorotate = NO and some shouldAutorotate = YES

Right now I don't think doing a transformation on just the rotating views is a good option?
Is there any other way?

I am using IOS 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to override `layoutSubviews` in your UIView to position and rotate your buttons and images the way you want them.  Check `[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation` in there to determine the current orientation, and rotate everything accordingly.  Depending on how you've implemented your view controller, you might also need to override `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` and/or `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` in your view controller to handle what happens before and after the rotation.

Comment: so I would put in my view controller shouldAutorotate = YES and in my layoutSubviews I would not be calling super but rotate wanted views

Comment: Correct.  You'll probably need to position the toolbar manually as well.

Comment: many thanx. couldn't it be dangerous not calling [super layoutSubviews]? anyway I 'ill try it out

Comment: The default layoutSubviews does nothing prior to iOS 6 (?) and in iOS 6 and up it just applies any constraints you have set.  Since you'll be overriding the subview positions manually anyway, you probably haven't set any constraints.  You can still call [super layoutSubviews] if you want, but it isn't necessary.

Comment: Sorry I tried overriding layoutSubviews with not much success. I am trying a new question "How-to prevent outer UIView (toolbars) from rotating around a shouldAutoRotate center view"

Comment: I think I am getting close... one think which irritates me is that the non-rotate-view animates into the right position. Maybe have to use a screenshot to make it look like that no toolbar rotation is taking place